# How to use getCurrentLocation of fused location provider client?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am new for Android coding, and have writen a code to get location of Android Device but failed. Nothing changed (e.g. `mLastKnownLocation` or `cityName`) after runing, and no expception. I have already checked permission and build.gradle. Could you give me advices to implement it?

```
private void getDeviceLocation() {
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {

                Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getCurrentLocation(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,cancellationToken);
                //Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Obtain the current location of the device
                            mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            String currentOrDefault = "Current";

                            if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Get current location");
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                                currentOrDefault = "Default";

                                // Set current location to the default location
                                mLastKnownLocation = new Location("");
                                mLastKnownLocation.setLatitude(mDefaultLocation.latitude);
                                mLastKnownLocation.setLongitude(mDefaultLocation.longitude);
                            }

                            String city = "CorrectCity";
                            try {
                                List<Address> address =
                                        geocoder.getFromLocation(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                        mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
                                if(address.isEmpty())
                                    city = "No_city";
                                else{
                                Address target = address.get(0);

                                if(target.getLocality()!=null)
                                    city = target.getLocality();
                                else
                                    city = target.getAdminArea();}
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
                            }

                            cityName = city;
                            // Show location details on the location TextView
                            String msg = currentOrDefault + " Location: " +
                                    Double.toString(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude()) + ", " +
                                    Double.toString(mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude())+ "  " +
                                    cityName;
                            locationTextView.setText(msg);

                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                            /*mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);*/
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
            cityName = "ErrorCity";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your last known location using the code below

```java
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
    if (location != null) {
        // your last known location is stored in `location`
    }
});
```

refer: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

---

**Using `Location Manager`**

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
        mMap.clear();
        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Me"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
};

manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

Comment: Dear sir, this not work for me. It just gets old data, because `getCurrentLocation()` is skipped for some unknown reason.

Comment: Did you try changing your device location? And where I've used `getCurrentLocation`?

Comment: In case of I'm using emulator, I have changed the location from "Extended Control"->"Location"->"Single Point", but `getLastLocation()` do not work for this change, while it gets an old location before change. As you can see the line under `getCurrentLocation()` in my code, I have  tried it.

Comment: is the code inside MapFragment?

Comment: I just want to show the location in textview rather than a map. Do I have to implement MapFragment in this case.

Comment: By the way, I have found that the my onCompleteListener is seemed to be skipped. When I debugging and force the code inside the listener runs, it works perfectly.

Comment: I updated the answer, try using location manager

Comment: @sern if it's the answer for your question, you can accept this answer

Comment: Sorry for replying late! I have tried `LocationManager` but still not work. However, I have found that my code`Task<Location> locationResult =                   mFusedLocationProviderClient.getCurrentLocation(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, cancellationTokenSource.getToken());`  running successfully in another project, but in this this project, I can only apply `getLastLocation()`.

Comment: Therefore, I have double checked my setting (manifest, API and gradle), but still have no idea. Do you have any ideas about this situation. If so, could you please tell me or post in your answer, I will accept it immidiately.